# How to add a partial phrase to multiple file names at the same time in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, rename, batch-rename

I have files named `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, etc, going all the way up to 500 image files.

I intend to put a word in front of the number, so the new file names would be `alpha-1.png`, `alpha-2.png`, `alpha-3.png` etc. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: This worked! Could you re-post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as resolved? Thank you so much btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %f in (*.png) do echo rename "%f" "alpha-%f"
```

It can get as complicated as you want it to, but for the exact example you ask this will work.

The `echo` command is so you can see what it will do before you run it. Then delete the echo command.

Also, the windows explorer is really cool this way you can highlight multiple files and then rename them with one name, you will end up with `your_title(n).ext` where n will be numbered.

Also.. @phuclv example in powershell is just as good (if not better) but more complicated.  The sooner people learn a more advanced interpreter, the better ;)

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell you can use either of these

```powershell
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { "alpha-" + $_.Name }
ls|ren -Ne{"alpha-" + $_.Name}
```

The latter is the aliased version of the former. You can also add `-WhatIf` or `-wi` to run dry and confirm that the command is correct or not